# npm errors and warnings in terminal

Tags: node.js, npm

can anybody tells me what are those errors about and how to fix them?
Everytime i try to install something in node with npm these errors show up in terminal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HBiV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is because you do not have package.json file. **Npm** installs the package in a node_modules/ subfolder, but warns you that there is no **package.json** file. If you want to manage localy installed **npm** packages you should create a **package.json** file. Start by creating an empty folder:

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
```

and then create a new package.json executing

```
$ npm init
```

Answer *(or skip)* all questions and at the end a brand new package.json will be created.

You can get more information from the **Getting started** articles in **npm** documentation: [Working with package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json)

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT stands for basically "Error, No Entry". this means it was looking for the package.json file and it couldn't find it.The fields mentioned below are also not found because they are a part of the package.json file

so create a package.json file in the current current directory using

```
npm init
```

and add the required content in the required fields
i would also recommend you to install the modules locally into the directory of the particular project using

```
npm install express --save
```

Hope my answer helps,
cheers